# Is there something wrong with the format of this nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I don't understand why this isn't working, I followed the tutorial I'm working from and I have been over it so many times. The tutorial in question hasn't run the code yet but I don't see any errors popping up in his code. The tutorial I'm following is at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERLT1iU0DVY specifically at 7 mins 40 to 8 mins 35.

According to visual studio, the error lies within the zone_map opening {
It says it hasn't been closed. As you can see this isn't the case.

Can someone please explain to me what the problem is?

```
ZONENAME = ''
DESCRIPTION = 'describe'
EXAMINATION = 'examine'
SOLVED = False
UP = 'up', 'north'
DOWN = 'down', 'south' 
LEFT = 'left', 'west'
RIGHT = 'right', 'east'

zone_map = {
    'a1': {
        ZONENAME: 'Western courtyard',
        DESCRIPTION = 'describe',
        EXAMINATION = 'examine',
        SOLVED = False,
        UP = '',
        DOWN = '',
        LEFT = '',
        RIGHT = 'a2'
    },
    'a2': { 
        ZONENAME: 'West-central courtyard',
        DESCRIPTION = 'describe',
        EXAMINATION = 'examine',
        SOLVED = False,
        UP = 'up', 'north',
        DOWN = 'down', 'south',
        LEFT = 'left', 'west',
        RIGHT = 'right', 'east', 
    },
}
```

[Error in VSC][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnxLA.png

I have tried:

- changing the commas at the end of each line to semi-colons which got rid of a lot of the red underscored lines.however, I reverted it as I suspect the lines were there because of the issue with the bracket.
- removing the content of the nested dictionary

Comment: The = in the dictionary need to be : and the keys need to be in quotes. That is not remotely valid python.

Comment: You should probably find a better YouTuber / tutorial...

Comment: fyi nobody should need to visit an external video to understand what you're trying to achieve. All details should be in your question.

Comment: Thank you @luk2302! I have no idea why he was using = signs, maybe I read it wrong but I'm sure it said at the beginning it was python 3. I'm new to python for a second time so I'm not even sure if that matters.

Comment: Noted @DavidMakogon, I will remember this for the future!

Answer (score 1):

Keys and Values in dictionaries are separated by `:`, not `=`. You are using both in some cases. Also, the keys of a dictionary need to be quoted. They are literals, not variables.:

So, this is closer, but still not right:

```
zone_map = {
    'a1': {
        'ZONENAME':'Western courtyard',
        'DESCRIPTION':'describe',
        'EXAMINATION':'examine',
        'SOLVED':False,
        'UP':'',
        'DOWN':'',
        'LEFT':'',
        'RIGHT':'a2'
    },
    'a2': { 
        'ZONENAME':'West-central courtyard',
        'DESCRIPTION':'describe',
        'EXAMINATION':'examine',
        'SOLVED':False,
        'UP':'up', 'north',
        'DOWN':'down', 'south',
        'LEFT':'left', 'west',
        'RIGHT':'right', 'east', 
    },
}
```

The last 4 keys (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT) have two values separated by a comma. You can't have two values for a single key, so I'm guessing those should be a list and square brackets would be appropriate. I haven't watched the tutorial, so this is a bit of a guess:

```
zone_map = {
    'a1': {
        'ZONENAME':'Western courtyard',
        'DESCRIPTION':'describe',
        'EXAMINATION':'examine',
        'SOLVED':False,
        'UP':'',
        'DOWN':'',
        'LEFT':'',
        'RIGHT':'a2'
    },
    'a2': { 
        'ZONENAME':'West-central courtyard',
        'DESCRIPTION':'describe',
        'EXAMINATION':'examine',
        'SOLVED':False,
        'UP':['up', 'north'],
        'DOWN':['down', 'south'],
        'LEFT':['left', 'west'],
        'RIGHT':['right', 'east'], 
    },
}
```

Now you can use it in your code:

```
>>>print(zone_map['a2']['Description'])

describe
```